# Probability density function for distance between two points.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, circles

Two points are chosen randomly inside a circle (and even on the circumference) with radius $r$ What is the probability density function of the distance between the points? I would be very grateful.

Comment: Hi!  Rather than treat this as a homework solving site, perhaps you could relate what you've tried so far, and how that's worked out.

Comment: Actually this is not a homework. I solved this by simulation (that was the homework). I just wanted some advices to proceed because i have not idea. i've  tried : let two points inside the circle $p_1$  and $p_2$ i fixed $p_1$ and tried to calculate the cumulative distribution of the distance between the points $F(d)=P(D\leq d)=\frac{area(circle with center p_1 and radius d)}{Total area}$ and derivate $F(d)$ to obtain the density $f(d)$ i can't figure out how to obtain $F(d)$ without fixing $p_1$